# IIS 7.5 Rewrite URL with Reverse Proxy from a default web site to two web sites failed

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I want the users to access my intranet test website - http://mywebsite:9090 if they type http://mywebsite/test.

I am following section - 7. Reverse Proxy To Another Site/Server in http://blogs.iis.net/ruslany/archive/2009/04/08/10-url-rewriting-tips-and-tricks.aspx to create a url rewrite.

After checked the “Enable proxy” checkbox located in Application Request Routing feature view in IIS Manager.  I have the rule as -

```
<rule name="Proxy">
  <match url="(.*/test)" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}:9090/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

However this does not work.  It does not direct me to http://mywebsite:9090 but prints out that http://mywebsite/test is not found.

Changed the rule to see if it is a proxy problem by using -

```
<rule name="Proxy">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}:9090/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

I can see it can direct me to http://mywebsite:9090 when I browse http://mywebsite.

What happens to my first rule?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Tittle of the question would be more informative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is the rule:

"^test(/.*)?$"

Your action can stay the same.

With the rule above, you're saying "if the first thing after the HTTP_HOST part of the url (which includes the first slash, i.e. "http://mywebsite.com/") is equal to test, then you
create a capture group on all of the rest of the URL (if there is any), rewrite the URL to have the HTTP_HOST, add the port 9090, and then append whatever was in the first capture group (i.e. R:1, whatever is in the parens in the regex).

Make sure you uncheck Append query string as you are capturing what you need as part of the Regex and don't need that.

Credit where's it due, I was struggling with solving this too and found what I needed here:

http://forums.iis.net/t/1180781.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  However it doesn't work for me.  When I type in http://mywebsite.com/test, I got validation error in IIS Url Rewrite's Test Pattern.  I might not make it clear enough.  What I want is I don't like to open 9090 to Internet.  When user types in http://mywebsite.com/test, IIS can internally rewrite http://mywebsite.com/test to http://mywebsite.com:9090 and present my testing site through port 80.  http://mywebsite.com/ is the production site using port 80 which is open to Internet.  Is it possible through URL rewrite?  Thanks again!

Comment: Try the following; use a blank rule, add the rule mentioned above as the match (make sure you are selecting Regex), and choose to redirect to a known working site like Google's site. Don't worry if it fails validation or not (though it shouldn't), test it by using it. Go to yoursite/test and see if you get redirected to Google. If you do, then you only need to work out the correct way to reference your site (i.e. mywebsite:9090). Hope that helps.

Comment: Brett, you are right.  It can direct me to Google.  I just need to figure out how to direct to mywebsite:9090.  Thanks!

Comment: Did you find the reason it was not working properly? Thanks :)

Comment: @Moulde - I don't know the exact problem Don was having, but I think it had to do with the 9090 port. Regardless, if you're having problems with this, I'd be glad to try and help if you post your specifics.